# query from two tables using laravel query builder + mysql

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables, one called quotations and the other called invoices. I want to retrieve all quotations without invoices. Below is the code I have so far. I can only retrieve all quotations. How can I modify this query

```
$quotations = Quotation::lists('id', 'id');
```

```
mysql> describe quotations;
+---      ----  --------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| customer_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| employee_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| exchange_rate | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0                   |                             |
| remark        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |                     |                             |
| created_at    | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| updated_at    | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
mysql> describe invoices;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| quotation_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| employee_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| amount       | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0                   |                             |
| balance      | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0                   |                             |
| created_at   | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| updated_at   | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

`Quotation::has('invoices', '<', 1)->get();`

This above code assumes you have a relationship set up in your `Quotation` model, ie:

```
class Quotation 
{
    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\Models\Invoice');
    }
}
```

The `has` method will check for the total number of items in the relationship you have defined as the first argument `invoices`. The second argument is the comparison of less than, the third is the count you want to compare to. So this will search for all Quotations with an invoice count of less than one.

You can read more [about querying relations here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) under **Querying Relationship Existence**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. please clarify more on your answer. 'invoice' isn't an attribute. I want to fetch all quotations that have no entries in the invoices table

Comment: Thanks for that answer, you answer is right but there you need to add ->get(); for it to work. it should be like Quotation::has('invoices', '<', 1)->get();

Comment: There, edited once more. If it's the right answer please mark it as such. And no problem, glad to help. I apologize for not quite giving the whole picture initially.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding the code below thanks to Emn1ty

```
$quotations = Quotation::has('taxInvoices', '<', 1)->get();
```